# $\frac{x-a}{\|x-a\|}+\frac{x-b}{\|x-b\|}=\lambda x,\ \|x\|=1$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations

Given $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$ outside the unit ball, I want to solve the system
$$\frac{x-a}{\|x-a\|}+\frac{x-b}{\|x-b\|}=\lambda x$$
$$\|x\|=1$$
Some comments with general ideas also would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is only a initial thought (as requested).

[image]

In the picture above, $OD\parallel AX$ and $OE\parallel BX$. Since $\vec{XA}=\vec{a}-\vec{x}$,
 $$\vec{OD}=\frac{\vec a- \vec x}{\| \vec a - \vec x\|}.$$
And similarly 
 $$\vec{OE}=\frac{\vec b- \vec x}{\| \vec b - \vec x\|}.$$

Thus for the equality holds, $OX$ has to be the angle bisector of $\angle DOE$. That also requires $X$ lies in the plane $ODE$, i.e $X$ lies in the plane $OAB$. And the $n$-dimensional problem turns to a 2-D problem.